# Add default value to date field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I would like to add current time as the default values to a date field(like NOW in solr) and I have tried using _timestamp by enabling it. He under is what I am trying to have

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "type1": {
            "properties": {
                "my_dateField": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "default": "doc['_timestamp']"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I later came across that _timestamp has been deprecated and will not be available on future release. Is there any way to use non-deprecated API and get this working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to use the `ingest node` for this, when the `_timestamp` is completely removed: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html